# I need the same steps for my main " if " statement to happen for main "elseif" and "else" statements

Tags: java

I have 3 main parts ..."If" "elseIf" and "Else"...Incase the user enters something other than "february", it goes to either "elseif" or "else" statements...but after going there, I want it to go back up to the if statement  Thanks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Compare {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] months1 =   {"january","march","april","may","june","july","augest","september","october","november","december"};
     String s1 = getInput("Enter a month ");

     if(s1.equals("february")) {
       System.out.println("It's time to go to the Disneyland !");
       String s2 = getInput("Enter another month: ");

       if(s2.equals("february")) {
          System.out.println("You already won a Disneyland ticket! Try another month.");
          String s3 = getInput("Enter another month: ");             

              if(Arrays.asList(months1).contains(s3.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println("You will go to Paris");
              }else{
                String s4 = getInput("Leave your name and phone number. We will call you back. ");
                System.out.println("Thanks for visiting! Goodbye !" + s4);
       }    

    }else if(Arrays.asList(months1).contains(s1.toLowerCase())){
      System.out.print("Sorry we don't have any specials yet");

    }else{
      System.out.print("Phahaha:))) choose sthg else");
    }

  }
        private static String getInput(String prompt) {
            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print(prompt);
            System.out.flush();

try {
    return stdin.readLine();
} catch (Exception e) {
    return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
  }

 }
```

Comment: what exactly is your question

Comment: 1. you only stated what you want to do, you forgot to mention what is your problem. 2. You don't have to declare the months array twice - you can use the same one

Comment: ooooo..So I can use it globally..Actually I have 3 main parts ..."If" "elseIf" and "Else"...Incase the user enters something other than "february", it goes to either "elseif" or "else" statements...but after going there, I want it to go back up to the if statement

Comment: Thanks for requesting clarifications

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with **switch**

```
switch(object)
{
    case 'february': do something; break;
    case 'march': do something; break;
}
```

Your code will be tidy

Comment: ohhh ya perfect..It will be really neat this way..But what if I do it with If statement? Is there anyway? I'm just curious..haha

Comment: Yes! it works too, but the code will be larger haha, try to put in order the satetments with the {} and you will understand your code better.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to repeat the code, you can try putting it in an endless loop with

```
while(true) { /*your code goes here */ }
```

If you want to exit if the user types 'february' you can either put a return statement in the if or you can use

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: awesome..Thanks ! So do you mean it's impossible to use plain If, If else and else statements instead of While, Do..While, or switch methods?